# How does one write a paper's `Reference` section?

Tags: bibliographies

Recently, I used LaTeX to translate a foreign paper. However, when I wrote the reference section, I encounter an issue.

My code/method is as follows:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}
 [1]P. Bhatia, J. Thirunarayanan, N. Dave, An expert-system based design of a SCARA  robot, Expert Systems with Applications 15 (1999) 99–109.

 [2] H. Canbolat, J. Hu, D.M. Dawson, A hybrid learning/adaptive partial state feedback controller for RLED robot manipulators, International Journal of
 Systems Science 27 (1996) 1123–1132.

 [3] H. Canbolat, J. Hu, D.M. Dawson, A hybrid learning/adaptive partial state feedback controller for RLED robot manipulators, in: Proceedings of the 34th
 IEEE Conference on Decision and Control, 1995, pp. 39–44.

 [4] S.P. Chan, H. Chen, An efficient algorithm for identification of SCARA robot parameters including drive characteristics, in: Proceedings of the 25th
 Annual Conference of the IEEE Industrial Electronics Society, vol. 2, 1999, pp. 1004–1019.

 [5] T. Das, C. Dülger, Mathematical modeling, simulation and experimental        verification of a SCARA robot, Simulation Modelling Practice and Theory 13
 (2005) 257–271.

 [6] M.S. De Queiroz, D.M. Dawson, H. Canbolat, Adaptive position/force control of BDC-RLED robots without velocity measurements, in: Proceedings of the
 IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation, 1997, pp. 525–530.

 [7] M.J. Er, C.B. Low, K.H. Nah, M.H. Lim, S.Y. Ng, Real-time implementation of a dynamic fuzzy neural network controller for a SCARA robot,
 Microprocessors and Microsystems 26 (2002) 449–461.

 [8] M.J. Er, M.T. Lim, H.S. Lim, A real time hybrid adaptive fuzzy control of a SCARA robot, Microprocessors and Microsystems 25 (2001) 369–378.

 [9] W. Golnazarian, Time-Varying Neural Networks for Robot Trajectory Control, Ph.D. Thesis, University Of Cincinnati, USA, 1995.

 [10] R. Horowitz, W. Messner, J.B. Moore, Exponential convergence of a learning controller for robot manipulators, IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control
 36 (1991) 890–894.

 [11] M. Jungbeck, M.K., Madrid, Optimal neural network output feedback control for robot manipulators, in: Proceedings of the Second International
 Workshop on Robot Motion Control, 2001, pp. 85–90.

 [12] K. Kaneko, R. Horowitz, Repetitive and adaptive control of robot manipulators with velocity estimation, IEEE Transactions on Robotics and Automation
 13 (1997) 204–217.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the output is not what I want. How can I revise it so I can achieve the effect of a professional paper?

Comment: I think that if you please take a look at one of these tutorials ([A](http://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/~hellmund/LaTeX/bibtex2.pdf), [B](http://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/latex/BIBTEX.HTM), [C](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/bibliographies), [D](http://www.bibtex.org/Using/)), your life will be easier. Please take a look and go through the one which suits you. Then if you face any specific issue, you will find this community more than willing to help. And welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: If you want to use the `thebibliography` environment, you might want to read the first section or two of [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Embedded_system).  The basic ideas are that each entry needs a `\bibitem{<some key>}` that can be referenced in your document with `\cite{<some key>}`.

Comment: If you expect to use (some, many, all of) the citations in multiple papers, you're better off using BibTeX and creating a bibliographical database.  The links referred to by @MMA explain the process.

Comment: @jon, Ok,I will have atrial based your hints

Comment: I second jon's suggestion. bibtex, biblatex, natbib, and others are very cool, but for a translation I would just use the `thebibliography` environment.

Comment: @jmc,@jon,I have achieve it by using `\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{...} \emph{...}\end{thebibliography}`Thanks very much.SE is very useful for my study!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `\bibitem` so separate the different items manually done bibliography.
 LaTeX does the numbering for you (but does no sorting).

An example from the [LaTeX-Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
I doubt that there is any useful information here~\cite{wikibook}.

All we know is limited, apart from knowing the answer we all know. Or do we? Wombat and Koala have discovered some interesting things~\cite{wombat2016}.

Some people are too nosy. What can happen to them is described by Laura Lion~\cite[p.~9]{lion2010}.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
    \bibitem{wombat2016}
        Walther Wombat and Klaus Koala,
        ``The true meaning of 42'' in: Journal of modern skepticism;
        2016
    \bibitem{lion2010}
        Laura Lion, Gabrielle Giraffe and Carl Capybara,
        ``The dangers of asking the wrong question'', publishing house;
        2010
    \bibitem{wikibook}
        manually managing references, 
        \url{https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References}
        2016
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: ManualRefA]

---

Using a database to store the information is less troublesome and more effective.